# How do I filter/show results (from JSON data) when using "keyup" on input?

Tags: javascript, arrays, dictionary, dom, filter

I’m trying to show just 3 items from an array as I filter them when the Event Listener "keyup" activates.
The problem is that it’s not filtering anything when I **show** the products (but in the console.log everything’s filtering correctly), but **it only shows the first 3 items from the array**, and not the filtered items.

I’ve tried using `slice(0,3)` when I use the map method on the array.

What am I doing wrong ?

Here’s the code:

```
var url = '/dataset.json';
let produits = [];
var productsList = document.getElementById("productsList")

const searchBar = document.getElementById('searchbar')
const noResults = document.getElementById('no-results')

// get data from JSON
fetch(url)
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then((output) => {
        produits = output
        console.log(produits)
        displayProducts(produits)

    })
    .catch(err => { throw err });


// Function that returns <li> items
const displayProducts = (produits) => {
    const htmlString = produits
        .slice(0, 3)
        .map((produit) => {
            return `
    <li class="produitWrapper">
        <div class="imgProduit">
            <img src="https://d1tydw6090df56.cloudfront.net/products/320x240/${produit.imageKeyHashes}.jpg"
                alt="">
        </div>

        <div class="infosProduit">
            <h2>${produit.title} - </h2>
            <h3>${produit.mpn}</h3>
            <br>
            <p>${produit.description}</p>
        </div>
    </li>
        `;
        })
        .join("");
    productsList.innerHTML = htmlString;
}

searchBar.addEventListener('keyup', (e) => {

    const searchString = e.target.value.toLowerCase();
    const produitsFiltres = produits.filter(item => {
        // noResults.style.display = "block";)

        return (
            item.mpn.toLowerCase().includes(searchString) ||
            item.description.toLowerCase().includes(searchString) ||
            item.title.toLowerCase().includes(searchString)
        )
    });
    console.log(produitsFiltres)
})
```

Comment: Maybe because you are calling, `.slice(0, 3)`? Also, shouldn't you be returning the `produits` inside the `then` of the promise and assigning it `const produits = fetch...`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know you forgot to call display product anyway the code below works

```js
let products = [{name: "andam"}, {name: "hiwa"}, {name: "Abd"}, {name: "Ev"}];

var productsList = document.getElementById("productsList")
const searchBar = document.getElementById('searchbar')


// Function that returns <li> items
const displayProducts = (products) => {
    const htmlString = products.slice(0, 3).map((product) => { return `<li>${product.name}</li>`; }).join("");
    productsList.innerHTML = htmlString;
}
searchBar.addEventListener('keyup', (e) => {
    const searchString = e.target.value.toLowerCase();
    const produitsFiltres = products.filter(item => {
        return (
            item.name.toLowerCase().includes(searchString)
        )
    });
    
    
    displayProducts(produitsFiltres)
})
```

```html
<input id="searchbar"/>
<ul id="productsList"></ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to call the following function again to repaint the HTML:
This time with the filtered values displayProducts(produitsFiltres)

I hope it is the right answer :)

Comment: You’re right! I was consoling log everything and forgot to call the function. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't you be returning the `output` inside the `then` of the promise and assigning it via `const produits = fetch...`?

Anyways, once you have your list of objects, you can filter from it whenever you need to display. Do not reassign the `produits` variable. Make sure it is `const`, because you always want the original list to start with when you begin to filter.

I created a generic `listToHtml` function below. You can simply call it by passing in your element, list, and business logic. It simplifies the code greatly and makes it 1,000% more readable.

```js
const baseUrl = 'https://d1tydw6090df56.cloudfront.net/products/320x240';
const productsList = document.getElementById('products-list');
const searchBar = document.getElementById('searchbar');

const produits = [
  { imageKeyHashes: '',  title: "Apple",  mpn: '', description: "A red fruit" },
  { imageKeyHashes: '',  title: "Banana", mpn: '', description: "A yellow fruit" },
  { imageKeyHashes: '',  title: 'Cherry', mpn: '', description: "A red fruit" },
  { imageKeyHashes: '',  title: 'Pear',   mpn: '', description: "A green fruit" }
];

const renderProduit = (produit) => `
  <li class="produit-wrapper">
    <div class="img-produit">
      <img src="${baseUrl}/${produit.imageKeyHashes}.jpg" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="infos-produit">
      <h2>${produit.title}</h2>
      <h3>${produit.mpn}</h3>
      <br>
      <p>${produit.description}</p>
    </div>
  </li>`;

const listToHtml = (targetElement, collection, rendererFn, predicateFn, limit) =>
  targetElement.innerHTML = collection
    .filter(predicateFn)
    .slice(0, limit)
    .map(rendererFn)
    .join('');

const displayProducts = (searchString) => {
  listToHtml(productsList, produits, renderProduit, item => {
    return (
      searchString === '' ||
      item.mpn.toLowerCase().includes(searchString) ||
      item.description.toLowerCase().includes(searchString) ||
      item.title.toLowerCase().includes(searchString)
    )
  }, 3);
};

const triggerEvent = (el, eventName) => {
  var event = document.createEvent('HTMLEvents');
  event.initEvent(eventName, true, false);
  el.dispatchEvent(event);
};

searchBar.addEventListener('keyup', e => {
  displayProducts(e.target.value.trim().toLowerCase());
});
triggerEvent(searchBar, 'keyup');
```

```css
h2, h3, p { margin: 0.1em; }
.produit-wrapper { list-style: none; }
```

```html
<div>
  <label>Search</label>
  <input type="text" id="searchbar" />
</div>
<div id="products-list"></div>
```